# How to Add Dictionary<String,String> Data in SolrNet

Tags: solrnet

I want to add record with Solr.net I am getting Error.

The remote server returned an error: **(400) Bad Request**.

my code is like this.

**In Schema file**

```
field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /><br>
field name="Tags" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

**In my class**

```
public class ProductTest2
{
  [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
  public int Id { get; set; }
[SolrField("Tags")]
public Dictionary<string, string> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

**Code where I want to add new Rows**

```
solr.Add(new ProductTest2()
{
  Id = i,
  Tags = new Dictionary<string, string> { { Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Filter1_ID"]), Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Filter1"]) } }
}
solr.Commit();
```

When I execute this code its showing error. But if I Remove the Dictionary Type and add another type then working fine. please suggest me what type I should give for Dictionary.
currently i have used `type="string"`.

Thanks in Advance.
Ashutosh
9818842034

Answer (score 2):

SolrNet supports mapping dictionaries to dynamic fields. In this case, the parameter of `[SolrField]` is a prefix for the field name. This is explained in more detail in the [SolrNet wiki](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Mapping#Dictionary_mappings_and_dynamic_fields).

If you want to use a multivalued field instead of a dynamic field to store dictionaries, it may be possible by implementing `ISolrDocumentPropertyVisitor`. It's not trivial to do so, though, and I don't think it's a good idea anyway.